# Missing error why spring boot app fails to start

Tags: spring-boot

I'm developing a spring boot application which is meant to run in Kubernetes. During development (either in Windows as well as in Linux) if there is an error e.g. in spring properties I get and error for that as the last line of the log-output:

```
...
2019-01-11 11:17:45.372  WARN 15528 --- [ost-startStop-2] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [easyprocesses] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser.run(BlockSource.java:327)
2019-01-11 11:17:45.407 ERROR 15528 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailCreationProperties': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'mailcreation.sender.email-address' in value "${mailcreation.sender.email-address}"
```

If I run the same application I do NOT get the error. There is no hint why the application did not start properly. This is what I get in Kubernetes:

```
...
2019-01-11 10:35:33.365  WARN 1 --- [ost-startStop-2] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [easyprocesses] appears to have started a thread named [oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource.ThreadedCachingBlockSource.BlockReleaser] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
     java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
```

oracle.jdbc.driver.BlockSource$ThreadedCachingBlockSource$BlockReleaser.run(BlockSource.java:327)

In both situations there are some shutdown issues (don't know why) but they are similar.

For example if the password of the underlying DB is wrong the application does not show that error either. This application stops and does not print any usable error.

Has anyone an idea what's the reason for this behaviour?

Thanks,
Stephan

Comment: check `mailcreation.sender.email-address` is available in `application.properties` file. Post `application.properties` file + `MailCreationProperties` class code.

Comment: Check how long you have in your liveness probe. Maybe the pod on k8s is being killed before it has got as far as logging the errors you expect to see. Also check that err isn't being redirected to a central logging (e.g. a logback profile being activated).